# Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm learning Laravel. I'm trying to create a form that list the cars in a cars table and if clicked, sends into another form which is based on a DB query that returns the data of the chosen car (identified by $modelesc).

This form sends the data to a "orders" table. With the code that I have now, I'm not able to post the order on the order table. it gets the message: "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:"

This is the code

Web.php

```
Route::get('catalog', 'carController@catalog');
Route::get('orders/', 'CarController@orders')->name('orders');
```

CarController

```
function catalog() {
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->get();
    return view('catalog', compact('cars'));
}

function orders(Request $request) {
    $modelesc = $request->modelesc;
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', $modelesc)->get();
    $colours = DB::table('colours')->get()->pluck('Colour');
    return view('orders', compact('cars', 'colours'));
}
```

Catalog.blade.php

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('$modelesc', $car->Model) !!}
{!! Form::submit($car->Model) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}   
@endforeach
```

Orders.blade.php

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST']) !!}
<a href="{{route('orders', $car->Model) }}">{{ $car->Model }}</a>
{!! Form::hidden('users_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('Fabrication_date', date('Y-m-d')) !!}
{!! Form::select('Colour_id', $colours) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Ok') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

The table orders has following structure:

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('Model');
        $table->date('Fabrication_date');
        $table->integer('Colour_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('Colour_id')->references('id')->on('colours')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('Order_status_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('Order_status_id')->references('id')->on('order_status')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your orders function

```
public function orders(Request $request) 
{
    $modelesc = $request->modelesc;
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', $modelesc)->get();
    ...
}
```

Catalog.blade.php

```
Form::hidden('modelesc', $car->Model)
```

The `value` of your hidden input will be read by `request->modelesc` and you will endup with a URL that looks like this `http://mysite.dev/orders?modelesc=toyota`.

**Some advice**

You using a form to only submit a hidden input. No user input. It seems to me it would be a easier to use simple anchors `<a></a>`.

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
    <a href="/orders?{{ $car->Model }}">{{ $car->Model }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Same result.

Make it nice with pretty URLs. Change your route definition

```
Route::get('orders/{modelesc}', 'CarController@orders')->name('orders');
```

And the anchor

```
<a href="/orders/{{ $car->Model }}">{{ $car->Model }}</a>
```

With named route

```
<a href="{{ route('orders', $car->Model) }}">{{ $car->Model }}</a>
```

And the function

```
public function orders($modelesc) 
{
     $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', $modelesc)->get();
     ...
}
```

Comment: I have used some of your suggestions, and managed to put orders working. The route changes didnt work. But now i have another problem. Check the edited first post.

Comment: If you want to `POST` add a new route for post `Route::post('orders', 'CarController@functionName')->name('orders');` And define a function that will take care of that.

Comment: You said my answer helped you get the main question working. And now you are solving a different question. If so, please kindly mark my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

change your route to:

```
Route::get('orders/{model}', 'CarController@orders')->name('orders');
```

after this change your Controller to:

```
public function orders($model) {
        $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', $model)->get();
        if(!count($cars)){
            abort(404);
        }
        $colours = DB::table('colours')->get()->pluck('Colour');
        //$status = DB::select('select * from order_status where id = ?', [1])->get(); //this variable is never used
        return view('orders', compact('cars', 'colours'));
    }
```

and now change your Catalog.blade.php

in your case you don't need a form for go in your order page

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
  <a href="{{route('order', ['model' => $car->Model])}}">{{ $car->Model }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Well, i had problems with the route, and tried not to changed it. I have update the orders table, and managed to get orders working, but now i have another problem.